# Implement two-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I need to implement two-dimensional array in PHP. Is it a correct way to do this?

```
   $constr = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) 
    {
      for ($j=0; $j < $ncons; $j++) {
        $constr[$i][$j]   = $set->getInd($i)->getConstr($j);
      }
    }
```

Comment: define "correct way" :)

Comment: Seems fine to me. Are you stuck somewhere ? What output you getting & what is your expected output ?

Comment: Off-topic. Belongs to: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You should have asked this question on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Code review for this would be too trivial though ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code as you have it is fine, but since you're using objects, it's best to cache them inside the outer loop:

```
$constr = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {

    $ind = $set->getInd($i);

    for ($j=0; $j < $ncons; $j++) {
        $constr[$i][$j] = $ind->getConstr($j);
    }
}
```

In this way, you're not repeating `$set->getInd($i)` for the inner loop.

Comment: I guess type of variable `Set` should implement `Iterator` (assuming it's set of objects).

Comment: @PLB Having an iterator would definitely make the code easier, but that part of the code is unfortunately not shared ;-)